# Adding key value pairs to an object

Tags: javascript

I have a loop that creates key value pairs; one of the statements does what I want which is to create multiple pairs during the loop. I'm confused on why the other statement doesn't work. Code that works:

```
        chart[2][ITEMNAME] = new Array("Gonzo", "Kermit", "Piggy", "Rowlf", "Big Bird", "Elmo");
        var hashmap=[];////Create hashmap and dump array values
        for (var each in chart){
            hashmap[each]={};
            for (var eachITEM in chart[each][ITEMNAME]){
                hashmap[each][chart[each][ITEMNAME][eachITEM]] = chart[each][DATA][eachITEM];
            }
        }
```

Code that doesn't work - all I did was replace the [chart[each][ITEMNAME][eachITEM]] with another string. The behavior I notice is that it replaces all the values to the last element, not appending pairs to the object.

```
        chart[2][ITEMNAME] = new Array("Gonzo", "Kermit", "Piggy", "Rowlf", "Big Bird", "Elmo");
        var hashmap=[];////Create hashmap and dump array values
        for (var each in chart){
            hashmap[each]={};
            for (var eachITEM in chart[each][ITEMNAME]){
                hashmap[each]["name"] = chart[each][DATA][eachITEM];
                // hashmap[each][chart[each][ITEMNAME][eachITEM]] = chart[each][DATA][eachITEM];
            }
        }
```

This is one of the objects of in my complete array of objects:

```
    var chart = new Array();

    chart[0] = new Array();
    chart[0][LEGEND] = "Widget Production";
    chart[0][ITEMNAME] = new Array("Big Widgets", "Little Widgets", "Medium Widgets", "Microwidgets");
    chart[0][DATA] = new Array(30,50,100,25);
    chart[0][COLORS] = new Array("lightblue","orange","red","lightgreen");
```

What I am trying to do is alphebetize elements in ITEMENAME while keeping the arrays aligned to DATA & COLORS.

Comment: How are you creating `chart`? Because `for (var each in chart)` will iterate the enumerable properties of whatever object `chart` is. You haven't shown what it is.

Comment: And perhaps more to the point: What is the information you're trying to organize? Because I'm fairly certain we can find a better way to organize it if we know what you're trying to achieve.